Really lost on how propositions Q4 and Q5 were derived: n-Queen problem Discrete Math Rosen Textbook
The context is the well-known n-Queens problem and on the textbook, the following compound proposition is given:
Let $p(i,j)$ be a proposition that is $True$ iff there's a queen in the $i$th row and $j$th column, where $i = 1...n$ and $j = 1...n$.

to check all row contains at least one queen: $Q_1 = \land_{i=1}^n\lor_{j=1}^np(i,j)$
to check at most one queen per row: $Q_2 = \land_{i=1}^n\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=j+1}^n(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(i,k))$

in the textbook it has typo of using $p(k,j)$ instead of $p(i, k)$ in some spots.


to check at most one queen per column: $Q_3 = \land_{j=1}^n\land_{i=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=i+1}^n(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(k,j))$
to assert at most one queen on the diagonals:

$Q_4 = \land_{i=2}^n\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=1}^{min(i-1,n-j)}(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(i-k,k+j))$
$Q_5 = \land_{i=1}^{n-1}\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=1}^{min(n-i,n-j)}(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(i+k,j+k))$



So, to find valid results we need: $Q = Q_1 \land Q_2 \land Q_3 \land Q_4 \land Q_5$
I'm not understanding how the Q4 and Q5 were exactly derived, whether it be the indices or the innermost conjunction, at all. The textbook didn't explain it much either. Really need someone to help break down for me. Kindly please help me here.
Here are the relevant screenshots from the textbook (in order):
https://i.sstatic.net/Jp93uQw2.png
https://i.sstatic.net/51VSVeIH.png
https://i.sstatic.net/DafzwI64.png
Also, in the textbook where it says "Note that squares (i,j) and (i', j') are on the same diagonal if either i + i' = j + j' or i - i' = j - j' [where or is exclusive here]" it should really say i + j = i' + j'

I'm curious where the confusion actually lies.  Is it the inclusion of the "min" on $Q_4, Q_5$ that is the problem?

@BrianMoehring Just really everything about it, that included. Not really understanding where the innermost conjunction is coming from, where the indices are coming from, and the min stuff.

@BrianMoehring Kindly could you please help break it down for me?

@RolandF Thanks for the answer, but I think there's some typos in you're answer (red "\and")

Rotating  coordinates in Q2,Q3 (i,j) to diagonal (k,l)=(i+j,i-j) in the conditon is trivial.Let the boundaries for all $\land$ in the form $$\land _{1\leq i\leq 8\land 1\leq j\leq 8}\  \neg Q\left(i'+i,j'+j\right) \dots $$

@RolandF  Sorry I'm not understanding what you just did there. Kindly if you could further elaborate

It might help you to write a computer program with subroutines that check these conditions.  Not really many ways to do it.  Q4 and Q5 are presumably checking one of them major diagonals and the other minor diagonals.

Ya now that I got time to think about it I think I understand how the book got it.

A square chess board has coordinates $$\left\{i,j\right\}: \bigwedge_{i,j}\left( \ 1\le i\le 8, \quad 1\le j  \le  8 \ \right) $$
Transform to diagonal coordinates in an infinite  lattice
$$\left\{w=i+j,z=i-j\right\}: \bigwedge_{(i,j)\in \mathbb Z^2}\left( \ 1\le i\le 8, \quad 1\le j  \le  8 \ \right) $$
$$\left\{ w,z \right\}: \bigwedge_{(w,z)\in \mathbb Z^2}\left( \ 1\le \frac{1}{2} (w+z)\le 8, \quad 1\le \frac{1}{2} (w-z) \le  8 \ \right) $$
$$\left\{ w,z \right\}: \bigwedge_{(w,z)\in \mathbb Z^2}\left( \ 2\le   (w+z)\le 16, \quad 2\le  (w-z) \le  16 \ \right) $$
$$\left\{ w,z \right\}: \bigwedge_{(w,z)\in \mathbb Z^2}\left( \ 2-z\le w\le 16-z, \quad 2+z\le  w \le  16 + z \ \right) $$
A plot in Mathematica
   RegionPlot[
    And[2 - w <= z <= 16 - w, 2 + w <= z <= 16 + w], 
    {w, -8, 8}, {z, 0,16}]


